# Why is this space dense in this Sobolev space? (Bochner spaces)

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $V$ be a separable Banach space, and let $H$ be a Hilbert space. We have the Hilbert triple
$$V \subset H \subset V^*.$$
By separability, there exists subspaces $V_k$ with $V_k \subset V_{k+1}$ such that $\bigcup_k V_k \subset V$ dense.

Let $W^{1} = \{ u \in L^2(0,T;V) : u' \in L^2(0,T;V^*), u(0) = u(T)\}$ and endow it with the norm
$$\lVert {u}\rVert_{W^1} = \lVert{u}\rVert_{L^2(0,T;V)} + \lVert{u'}\rVert_{L^2(0,T;V^*)}.$$
Let $S_k = \text{span}(\varphi v : v \in V_k, \varphi \in C([0,T]), \varphi(0) = \varphi(T)\}$.
The claim is that $\bigcup_k S_k$ is dense in $W^1.$

No idea why this is true?

Comment: Could you explain what is $u'$ in this vector-valued setting?

Comment: @Etienne $u$ has weak derivative $u' \in L^2(0,T;V^*)$ if $\int_0^T u(t)\varphi'(t) = -\int_0^T u'(t)\varphi(t)$ holds for all $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(0,T).$

Comment: I think we need more context here. How is defined $u(0)$ and $u(T)$? Is this some kind of boundary trace? WHere do you found this problem?

Comment: @Tomás Recall that $W^1 \subset C([0,T];H)$ by Sobolev embedding, where $V \subset H \subset V^*$ is Gelfand triple. I should've included that. This problem is in the book by Roubicek's Nonlinear PDEs swith Applications, page 264 (see footnotes).

Comment: I think it is better to include this information on the question.

Comment: @aere: thanks for the clarification; but what is $V^*$? The notation $V^*$ usually means "the dual space of $V$", but this does not seem to be the correct interpretation in the present setting.

Comment: @Etienne, if $u:(0,1)\to V$ is a function, then by definition (in this case weak derivative) $u'(t)$ is a bounded linear functional for almost every $t$, which implies that $u':(0,1)\to V^\star$.

Comment: @Tomás : I still don't understand. In your post (definition of $\mathcal C^1$), $u'$ takes its values in $V$, not in $V^*$. And this seems quite reasonable!

Comment: @Etienne, that's because $V$ belongs to a Gelfand triple, i.e. there exist a Hilbert space $H$ such that $V\subset H\subset V^\star$, with some additional properties. I asked Aere to include this information in the question, but...

Comment: OK, now I understand better. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomás Cool down I was just about to include it!!

Answer (score 3):

First we note that $V_k$ can be choosen to be a finite dimensional space. Now we can find a sequence $v_k$, such that $v_1,...,v_n$ is a basis for $V_n$ for all $n$. Moreover, we choose $v_k$ in such a way that $$\tag{1}\|v_k\|\leq\frac{1}{2^k}$$

Note that $C^1=\{u\in C([0,1];V):\ u'\in C([0,1];V)\ \mbox{and}\ u(0)=u(T)\}$ is dense in $W^1$. This can be showed by using convolution, similar to what is done in Lemma 7.2. of the book you have cited.

Now, the only thinkg we need to prove is that $\cup S_k$ is dense in $C^1$. To this end, fix some $t\in [0,1]$ and note that for this $t$, there exist a family $(\alpha_k(t))$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k(t)v_k\to u'(t)\ \mbox{in}\ V\tag{2}$$

Choose $\epsilon>0$ and take $\delta>0$ such that $$\|u'(t)-u'(s)\|\leq\epsilon,\ \mbox{for}\ |t-s|\leq \delta\tag{3}$$

Take $s$ as in $(3)$ and define $\alpha_k(s)=\alpha_k(t)+s-t$. Note that (by using $(2)$ and $(3)$) $$\|\sum_{k=1}^n\alpha_k(s)-u'(s)\|\leq 3\epsilon \tag{4}$$

Now, we cover $[0,1]$ with a finite number of open sets, and we construct functions $\alpha_k(s)$ similar to that in $(4)$ to conclude that for each $t$ the convergence in $(2)$ is valid where $alpha_k$ is a continuous function. Because $[0,1]$ is compact, we conclude that the functions $\alpha_k$ are uniformly continuous which implies that the convergen in $(2)$ does not depend on $t$. Therefore, $$u'(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \alpha_k(t)v_k\tag{5}\ \mbox{uniformly}$$

We can therefore integrate $(5)$ to get that $$u(t)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int\alpha_k(t)v_k,\ \mbox{uniformly}$$

Comment: Thanks man let me read and understand it..